C++23 constexpr size limitations? Iterating through 0x4000 = ok, to 0x5000 = not a constant expression
The following code works and prints the intersection as expected. However, changing max_codepoint from 0x4000 to 0x5000 and it stops working with the error:
ConsoleApplication1.cpp(149, 30): [C2131] expression did not evaluate to a constant
I tried to change the 0x4000 to 0x5000 (or, more accurately, 0xffff to get the full UTF-16 range) and expected it to work. Yet, it doesn't.
#include <array>
#include <print>
#include <vector>

using ImWchar = unsigned short;

consteval std::vector<ImWchar> ConstGetGlyphRangesLatin()
{
    return {
        0x0020, 0x00FF, // Basic Latin + Latin Supplement
    };
}

consteval std::vector<ImWchar> ConstGetGlyphRangesGW()
{
    return {
        0x20, 0x7f,
        0xa1, 0xff,
        0x100, 0x180,
        0x0391, 0x0460,
        0x2010, 0x266b,
        0x3000, 0x3020,
        0x3041, 0x3100,
        0x3105, 0x312a,
        0x3131, 0x318f,
        0xac00, 0xd7a4,
        0x4e00, 0x9fa6,
        0xf900, 0xfa6b,
        0xff01, 0xffe7
    };
}

consteval bool in_range(const ImWchar c, const std::vector<ImWchar>& range)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < range.size() - 1; i += 2) {
        if (c >= range[i] && c <= range[i + 1]) return true;
    }
    return false;
};

consteval std::vector<ImWchar> find_glyph_range_intersection(const std::vector<ImWchar>& range1, const std::vector<ImWchar>& range2)
{
    if (range1.empty() || range2.empty()) return {};

    std::vector<ImWchar> intersection;
    wchar_t start = 0;
    bool in_intersection = false;

    constexpr auto max_codepoint = 0x4000;
    for (ImWchar c = 0; c <= max_codepoint; ++c) {
        const bool in_both = in_range(c, range1) && in_range(c, range2);

        if (in_both && !in_intersection) {
            start = c;
            in_intersection = true;
        }
        else if (!in_both && in_intersection) {
            intersection.push_back(start);
            intersection.push_back(c - 1);
            in_intersection = false;
        }
    }

    if (in_intersection) {
        intersection.push_back(start);
        intersection.push_back(max_codepoint);
    }

    intersection.push_back(0); // Null-terminate the range
    return intersection;
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
consteval std::array<T, N> vec_to_array(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::array<T, N> arr = {};
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr.begin());
    return arr;
}

consteval auto get_intersection_array()
{
    const auto latin = ConstGetGlyphRangesLatin();
    const auto gw = ConstGetGlyphRangesGW();

    const auto intersect = find_glyph_range_intersection(latin, gw);
    return vec_to_array<ImWchar, 1'000>(intersect);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array arr = get_intersection_array();
    for (auto c : arr) {
        if (c != 0)
            std::print("{}, ", c);
    }
}


Compiles for me with clang once I fixed ConstGetGlyphRangesKorean.  You're probably just hitting an internal compiler limit.  Check visual studio's manual to see if there's a way to increase the limit.

"What am I misunderstanding there?" That compile-time is not infinite. Compilers don't have to let constant evaluation continue forever. They can, and will, shut down execution if they feel like whatever you're doing has become pathological and cannot complete in a reasonable amount of time.

So, you've posted code that works, and in your question you provide instructions to change it to show the problem that you're asking about? Don't do that. Post the code that shows the problem.

@PeteBecker doesn't really change anything, does it? It's literally changing one letter.

@StephenNewell Interesting. What compiler are you using? Godbolt fails on gcc x64 latest and msvc x64 latest. I can't find documentation about such a setting, unfortunately.

clang 17.0.6 with libc++ 17.0.6, x86_64 linux (gentoo specifically, not that I think it matters).

Thank you. The limit for gcc actually appears to be a little higher than on MSVC, which is where I initially tested. Found the /constexpr compiler flag, resolves the issue.

@DubbleClick -- it's about providing code that someone can cut and paste and compile and see the problem. When you're asking people to do you a favor, make it as easy as you can for them. I, for one, wouldn't bother with code that I have to modify.

An expression is not a constant expression if evaluating it would require more evaluation steps than some implementation-defined limit.
That's to make sure that compilers aren't forced to work forever during compilation. Because of the halting problem it would otherwise be undecidable whether an expression is a constant expression.
Compilers usually have an option with which this implementation-defined limit can be increased, trading for compilation time.
As mentioned in a comment by @DubbleClick under this answer: The setting for MSVC seems to be /constexpr:steps.

Thank you for the answer. If anyone else is looking for the flag for MSVC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/constexpr-control-constexpr-evaluation?view=msvc-170

@DubbleClick I added that to the answer. However, you can also suggest edits to an answer by clicking "Edit" or write your own answer with more details. Comments can be deleted and are not guaranteed to remain.

Alternative, when possible, is to change to a less complex algorithm (in_range is linear here, might be logarithmic).
